# CakePHP writing file in TMP folder

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am getting permission error while writing file in TMP folder of CakePHP

My code is below in which I am writing a file with .xml extension in tmp folder but getting permission error.

```
        $docroot = TMP_FILE . "files/";
        $filename = $this -> request -> data['xmlEditor_Name'];
        $filename = $docroot . DS . $filename . '.xml';
        $filename1 = $this -> request -> data['xmlEditor_Name']. '.xml';
        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
        $xml .= $this -> request -> data['xmlEditor_Document'];         

        $handle = fopen($filename, 'x+') or die('Permission error');            
        fwrite($handle, $xml);
        fclose($handle);
```

Comment: What is constant `TMP_FILE` set to?

Comment: It works like WWW_ROOT but I am trying to store files in TMP folder in CakePHP

Comment: Ok. But is the constant actually defined?

Comment: no. wants to use cakephp predefined constant TMP for temp folder.

Comment: Then you should perhaps use `TMP` instead of `TMP_FILE`, which does not exist.

Comment: Yeah it works . Thanks